# Can I do an Insert inside a Stored Procedure using the default value? MariaDB

Tags: stored-procedures, insert, mariadb

I know that the code below works and assigns the default value established in the DB properties. My question now is how can use that inside a Stored Procedure and assign the default value in the DB structure in the event of a NULL input.
Currently using MariaDB.

This works:

```
insert into userclients (UserTypeID, UserName, UserPassword, UserEmail, UserBirthDate, UserFavouriteCategory) 
values (1, 'Daniel', 'DanielPassword', 'daniel@test.com', '1999-01-01', default);
```

Definition of the column in question:

```
UserFavouriteCategory varchar(100) not null default "All",
```

Now I would like to do something like:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE INSERT_USERCLIENT2(UserTypeIDInput int,UserNameInput varchar(100), UserPasswordInput varchar(100), UserEmailInput varchar(100), UserBirthDateInput date, UserFavouriteCategoryInput varchar(100) )
begin

insert into userclients (UserTypeID, UserName, UserPassword, UserEmail, UserBirthDate, UserFavouriteCategory) 
values (UserTypeIDInput, UserNameInput, UserPasswordInput, UserEmailInput, UserBirthDateInput, IFNULL(UserFavouriteCategoryInput, default) );

END $$

DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER $$
```

Is this possible in any way? I actually have 2 fields in the same situation and I would like to avoid nested IF's or multiples Stored procedures.

Comment: The column already has a constraint, in case of a NULL value the default value will be used. So why do you need an additional IFNULL() ?

Comment: Because the column is set as NOT NULL when a NULL value is passed an error occurs.
And without the NOT NULL an error will not occur, but the default value won't be used either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it's a problem with the default keyword, you can try passing the full identifier name of the column, this is an example:

```
create table test.test_table(
 id int,
 txt varchar(30) default 'This is the default!!'
 );

 -- Insert the default value
 insert into test.test_table values(1,default);

 -- Some value
 insert into test.test_table values(1,ifnull('A Value',test.test_table.txt) ); 

-- If null, insert the default value
 insert into test.test_table values(1,ifnull(null,test.test_table.txt) ); 

 select *
 from test.test_table;
```